# sqlx Unable to use Struct Scan with nested structs

Tags: go

I have different types for a REST API which have some things in common:

1. All types have *Id*
2. All types have *Type*
3. All types have *Attributes*, but Attributes differ

As I would not like to have a big count of unnecessary types I came up with a type format but which does not seem to be scannable by sqlx.

```
type Pool struct {
   Id *string `json:"id" db:"pool_id"`
   Type *string `json:"type"`
   Attributes struct {
       Name *string `json:"name" db:"name"`
       Description *string `json:"description" db:"description"`
   } `json:"attributes"`
}

type User struct {
   Id *string `json:"id" db:"user_id"`
   Type *string `json:"type"`
   Attributes struct {
       FirstName *string `json:"first_name" db:"first_name"`
       LastName *string `json:"last_name" db:"last_name"`
   } `json:"attributes"`
}
```

When trying to load the SQL result into the variable I get an error: `missing destination name name in *main.Pool`

```
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

func selectOne() interface{} {
    pa := Pool{}
    err := dbx.Get(&pa, "SELECT * FROM pools LIMIT 1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return pa
}
```

As name is present I do not see why this does not work. Any advice how to solve this is highly appreciated!

Comment: A SQL result is a set of columns, not hierarchically structured data. `sqlx` maps columns to struct fields. If you want to do something like this, you could embed your common attributes instead of making it a field (though using an anonymous type as in your example it's unclear why you're doing it this way at all).

Comment: I am trying to do it that way to be able to give the correct JSON API output by just marshalling the variable with the given type. Other solutions are very welcome.

Comment: If your JSON is hierarchically structured and coming from a flat unstructured source (like SQL) you may need to use separate types to represent each.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: is `Attributes` another sql table? if yes, then you would need to JOIN it in your sql query

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    _ "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

   
func selectOne() interface{} {
    pa := Pool{}
    err := dbx.Get(&pa, `SELECT p.id, p.type, a.name AS "attributes.name" FROM pools p left join attributes a on a.p LIMIT 1`)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return pa
}
```